# Elements missing in Gnome when awaking laptop from Sleep

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nvidia, wayland

I'm having an issue with Gnome (version 42.9 Wayland) running on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. When I open the lid after most elements in the desktop are missing their icons. The computer is an HP Zbook G6 with a NVIDIA Quadro RTX 4000 Mobile / Max-Q.

The Nvidia driver installed is Driver Version: 535.154.05, CUDA Version: 12.2.

Most apps like browsers, the terminal and so on will display just fine..

Does anyone know where to start looking?

[image]

The log shows this messages

```
gnome-shell[5115]: g_settings_get_value: assertion 'G_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
gnome-shell[5115]: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
gnome-shell[5115]: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
gnome-shell[5115]: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
```